# How to retrieve key object from datastore returned object

Tags: go, datastore

Here is a method, which retrieves all orders for given order id of the user

```
func (r *DatastoreRepository) FindOrders(ctx context.Context, userID string, orderIDs []string) ([]*domain.Order, interface{}) {
    keys := make([]*datastore.Key, len(orderIDs))
    for i, orderID := range orderIDs {
        key := datastore.NameKey(kindOrder, orderID, nil)
        key.Namespace = userID
        keys[i] = key
    }

    orders := make([]*domain.Order, len(keys))
    multiErrors := r.client.GetMulti(ctx, keys, orders)

    return orders, multiErrors
}
```

This method returns `*[]domain.Order` to my service method. Now service method wants to get access `key` object of a given order (in order to delete an order). One way to do it is re-create key for every order based on order id but this sounds like a code redundancy (i am doing it in `FindOrders` as well and would have to do it in `DeleteOrders` as well). Is there a way that i can access `datastore.key` object for a given order from `order object`?

Comment: Show the type declaration for Order.  Does it have a key field or an id field?

Comment: I don't know, can you? There's not enough information provided in the question to answer it, but if you have access to the source it should be easy to tell what fields you can access from which object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that an `Order` has an `ID` field, simply loop over the elements and set the field.

```
func (r *DatastoreRepository) FindOrders(ctx context.Context, userID string, orderIDs []string) ([]*domain.Order, interface{}) {
    keys := make([]*datastore.Key, len(orderIDs))
    for i, orderID := range orderIDs {
        key := datastore.NameKey(kindOrder, orderID, nil)
        key.Namespace = userID
        keys[i] = key
    }

    orders := make([]*domain.Order, len(keys))
    multiErrors := r.client.GetMulti(ctx, keys, orders)

    // Add this for loop...
    for i, order := range orders {
       order.ID = orderIDs[i]
    }

    return orders, multiErrors
}
```